# How to read ips in a file and assign each one with a variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a file ip.txt with a set of ips one per line and more than 400 ips as below

```
10.xx.xx.111
10.xx.xx.113
```

How can I assign each one of them to a separate variable like ip1=first line ip, ip2=second line ip and so on the last ip. The file has no delimiter as such, simply one ip per line.

I tried the below batch

```
@echo off
echo.
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (ip.txt) Do Set "%%A=%%B"
set | find /i "10="
```

But didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is a very simple task to achieve, however, there seems little reason to save each one of those lines to a separate variable. Can you please explain what the task is so that I can understand why you would need this!

Comment: Use findstr to number the lines `for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" ip.txt') Do Set "IP%%A=%%B"` and then just `set ip`

Comment: The problem I have is that I do not understand what code would need for example to use `%IP267%` as opposed to any other. It is more likely that your code can read each line and perform a task on each, _with a possibility of excluding one or more, (can be done with an `If` or a `Find`/`FindStr`)_.

Comment: I need to call each ips separately to find some packages installed inside it and I have working code to find that only when I give ip when it prompts. Basically for a large set of IPs say 400, there can be human mistakes. So i would want to automatically assign each line ips into a variable that is used as input for each iteration until the ips end in the file..

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I managed to set variables for each ip in the file. The variables assigned are like 
1stip=10.xx.xx.xx 2ndip=10.xx.xx.xx and so on till the last ip on the list.. 
Now how to do a common job on all these ips in the file which are assigned to variables.
Lets consider a simple ping on all variables which is holding the ip value.

Tried with for loop but no luck.. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @PrasannaRam , that's exactly the point I was making at the outset, there is no need to set those items as individual variables in the file. You can read those lines from the file and perform the actions without setting them as individual environment variables. If you have a question with a specific task, please edit your original question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from what I understand, based on your comments, you simply want a straight forward loop like this, to perfom a single task, for multple listed lines in a file:

```
@for /f %%i in (ip.txt) Do @echo %%i
```

Which will take each ip and do something with it, in this case `echo` it.

Where you would then obviously need to do something else with the IP, like ping it, connect to it etc. like:

```
@for /f %%i in (ip.txt) Do @ping %%i
```

Or do multple items in a code block to it:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (ip.txt) Do (
      echo %%i
      ping %%i
      nslookup %%i
)
```

If you REALLY want to set it as a veriable, which is REALLY not needed here, you can do it, but to use inside of the code block with things like `echo` etc, you would need `delayedexpansion`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in (ip.txt) Do (
      set "ip=%%i"
      echo !ip!
      ping !ip!
      nslookup !ip!
)
```

Comment: Many thanks, i was able to perform the tasks without assigning the IPs to the variables.
I have another question, my output file contains the below

1:id1:cluster_id:sys_name:Prim_vvol:sec_vvol:2019/02/18/03/36/47
2:id2:cluster_id:sys_name:Prim_vvol:sec_vvol:2019/02/18/03/36/47

How can i perform some operation like checking status of all ids.

lstype "1" show status
lstype "2" show status
The first number delimited by : is enough for code. Please guide if the first number 
on all line can be stored in variable or can be run similar to above taking only numbers through the loop.

Comment: Then just do `for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%i in (file...`